# how to pass path to an image directory in argument parser?

Tags: python, parsing, arguments

i have a folder containing a set of images. How can i pass it's path to the argument parser which i have constructed in the following way:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The path i want to pass is `home/downloads/images`

Currently i am getting this error:

```
usage: detect.py [-h] -i IMAGES
detect.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--images
```

Comment: You're not setting the flag. If you are, then please provide the shell from when the script crashes.

Comment: @HampusLarsson what do you mean by setting the flag? can you give an example according to question>

Comment: I'm facing the same issue..Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Demo: import images')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--images',
                    nargs='?',
                    required=True,
                    help='path to images directory')
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Bingo:", args.images)
```

call like this:

```
./detect.py -i home/downloads/images
```